# Break down Europe more in the survey results

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-developer-survey

So, my guess is that the [survey results](https://www.surveymonkey.com/sr.aspx?sm=vU4rF_2bPVQaftSo1s69bGGbvMPXp7ktcfSHiDFP_2bM5qw_3d) are fixed for this year, but for future years I think it a good idea to further segment "Other Europe". Right now, its percentage (>16%) is higher than any other save the US and I find that number misleading. Alexa.com suggests that Sweden and Austria might both be good candidates.

Comment: Not really the most useful feature in the world, but it also is very cheap to implement.

Comment: Just put in every country from the ISO 3166-1 list...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I think that some aggregation will be necessary, but with the Czech Republic ranking above Canada in [Alexa's traffic ranks](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com), I wonder if a little less aggregation might be interesting.

Comment: The Czech Republic is well below Canada in that list @cwallenpoole. More surprising is that South Korea is below Romania, and so is Italy...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Ah, you're right, I was looking at `Stackoverflow.com’s Regional Traffic Ranks` which is a very different number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/42162/which-country-are-the-users-from), Spain (which is also "Other Europe" in the survey) beats Italy (which is "Italy") by a close 4458 users to 4456. To mention other countries you have mentioned, Sweden has 5279 users, beating Spain and Italy; Austria has 1789, and the Czech Republic 1804.

The ten top European countries by users are: (in Bold, the ones which appear as individual countries in the survey)

1. **United Kingdom** 25976
2. **Germany** 12444
3. **France** 7511
4. **Russia** 7346
5. **Netherlands** 6364
6. Sweden 5279 ("Other Europe")
7. Spain 4458 ("Other Europe")
8. **Italy** 4456
9. Poland 4100 ("Other Europe")
10. Ukraine 3669 ("Other Europe")

I'd suggest to just ask with the full list when the survey is done, and *afterwards* maybe group the answers. In that way, the Other Europe countries would always be the ones which are not at the top of the list.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. But would aggregation be significantly more work?